# How to know maximum curvature degree on UTP cable?

Tags: cable-management

I don't know if here is the right place to ask this question.
Well, I want to know how to calcule (or if it is on a standar) the maximum curvature degree for UTP cat. 6 cables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean the minimum bend radius, then it is four times the cable diameter for UTP cables. This is detailed in *ANSI/TIA/EIA 568 Commercial Building
Telecommunications Cabling Standard*.

Exceeding the minimum bend radius or maximum pulling tension can permanently damage a cable.

Comment: Thaks, I was searching in Google for it, but I didn't know how to search it.